# How can I get the select option values in scrapy using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I need to get all the option values from select tag

```
<select name="Department" tabindex="3">
    <option  type="text" size="3" maxlength="2" value=""></option>
    <option  value="CSC">CSC</option>
    <option  value="IT">IT</option>
    <option  value="MCA">MCA</option>
    <option  value="BE">BE</option>
</select>
```

I tried `response.css('select::attr(name:Department)').extract()` but not getting.

I need output :

```
['CSC', 'IT', 'MCA', 'BE']
```

I am new to web scrapy please help...

Comment: I got answer using response.css('select[tabindex*="3"] option::text').extract()

Comment: please send it as an answer

Comment: sry to late rpy.   ['CSC', 'IT', 'MCA', 'BE']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is it using **xpath**.

```
response.xpath('//select/option/text()').getall()
```

One should use xpath as they are more powerful then the css selectors.
This is specified on [scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#xpath-a-brief-intro) itself (below thing).

> XPath expressions are very powerful, and are the foundation of Scrapy Selectors. In fact, CSS selectors are converted to XPath under-the-hood. You can see that if you read closely the text representation of the selector objects in the shell.

You can know more about them from [selectors](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html).

Comment: This will return the list of texts of each option. For values, it should be

response.xpath('//select/option/@value)').getall()

Comment: @AnshulTiwari Your comment has an extraneous `)`. The xpath should be `'//select/option/@value'`.

Comment: @AnshulTiwari Also, you should post this as an answer.

Comment: If I have more than one selection field, how can I specify the field id, for example?

Comment: I found out: using `response.xpath('//select[@id="id_select"]/option/@value').getall()`